# Re-inspection of values in a Traceback

Tags: python, exception, evaluate

I am trying to do some elaborate re-inspection of a traceback and get actual values 
from the objects that are failing to return more (better?) information along with 
the traceback.

The case scenario is in a function that I import and execute that looks like this:

```
def foo():
    a = True
    b = False
    assert a == b
```

And gets executed like:

```
from foo import foo

def re_inspect():
    try:
        foo()
    except Exception, e:
         # re-inspect traceback and check `a` and `b`
```

When the `AssertionError` gets raised, if I try to evaluate the line where the exception is raised, I am (of course) unable to tell what `a` or `b` is (`NameError` gets raised immediately) because I am lacking the context of the code.

Do note that I *do not* have access to `a` nor `b` as the code above is imported and then executed. Since `foo` does not live in the current name space, my problem relies on getting the correct values from the `foo` context.

What would be the right approach to be able to tell what `a` and `b` are so that y can safely say something like: "a is True and be is False" ?

Comment: I assume you're unable to edit `foo()`?

Comment: right, it is arbitrary code that I need to execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use inspect module :

```
try:
    foo()
except AssertionError, e:
    import inspect
    previous_trace = inspect.trace()[1]
    frame = previous_trace[0]
    print 'value of a, b:', inspect.getargvalues(frame).locals
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargvalues

Comment: This method still work even after you've edited your question :)

Comment: Absolutely right. Thanks for taking the time to edit your answer and nail it!

Comment: Just tried it and worked like a charm. On a side note, `locals` returns a dict with all the args so I had to `get('a')` from locals for the `a` value. If I could give you another point I would :)